# Initializing a Map using Mule Expression Language

Tags: mule

I'm trying to initialize a map with the following in a mule expression-component:

```
  #[message.payload = [ 'changeSet' : #[payload], 'sourceAndConnectionMap' : #[flowVars['sourceAndConnectionMap']]]]
```

Based on the following page, this looks okay, but does not work.
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference

Only the first key is set ('changeSet'), and for some reason the payload, which is a map, becomes an ArrayList containing a map...  I can also initialize this with just the second key and valy, so I know there isn't an issue resolving the flowVar.

Is there something basic about how I am initializing this map that is incorrect?

Comment: Weird, yours actually threw an exception when I tested it on expression-component.. It seems correct to me. Anyway, can you try this instead?  `payload = [ 'changeSet' : payload, 'sourceAndConnectionMap' : flowVars.sourceAndConnectionMap]`

Comment: @TyroneVillaluna is correct, the issue comes from the wrongly nested `#[]` inside the MEL expression.

Comment: thanks all.  the above suggestion works.

Answer (score 0):

In MEL a map should be created like:

```
#[{'key':'value', 'key1':'value1'}]
```

If you do

```
#[[]]
```

That's just a list of elements.

The other comments, if you're already inside a:

```
#[]
```

You need not to add it again. In your example you have it several times.

Please run this through the Mule debugger (put brakepoints in the logs)and you'll see the difference.

```
<flow name="test> 
<set-payload value="#[{'key':'value', 'key1':'value1'}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/> 
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> 
<set-payload value="#[{'key':'value', 'key1':payload}]" doc:name="Copy_of_Set Payload"/> 
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Copy_of_Logger"/> 
<set-payload value="#[['key','value', 'key1','value1']]" doc:name="Copy_of_Set Payload"/> <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

HTH

Comment: Looking at the docs, I think a map is initialized with [key1 : value1, key2 : value2].  A list is initialized as [ item1, item2] and an array is initialized by {item1, item2}.    https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference